Efficient Incremental Update Strategy for Large Datasets in Azure Blob Storage and Azure Search
I'm working on a project that involves storing and syncing large datasets using Azure Blob Storage and Azure AI Search. I'm facing performance challenges, and I’d love some advice on best practices for handling this efficiently.
Current Approach:
Storage: Data is stored in a flattened JSON structure in Azure Blob Storage.
Sync Process:

Retrieve JSON blobs and sort by the Last-Modified timestamp in
metadata.
Sync only the top 1000 updated records due to API limitations.
Save the last synced timestamp to optimize future operations.

Challenges:

No Built-in Sorting: Azure Blob Storage doesn’t support server-side
sorting by metadata, requiring local sorting.
Performance Issues: Fetching metadata for all blobs is inefficient
with large datasets (hundreds of gigabytes).
Timestamp Consistency: Ensuring consistent sync when blobs share
identical timestamps.

Questions:

How can I efficiently handle large datasets to perform incremental
updates without retrieving all metadata?
Are there alternative strategies or tools for managing sorting and
pagination?
How can I ensure synchronization consistency when timestamps are
identical?

What I've Tried:

Searching online for strategies but found limitations in existing
solutions.
Tested some Azure services but faced scalability issues.

Any insights, tools, or strategies would be greatly appreciated!

Hi, this is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, needs more focus. Read how to ask

Add what you have tried so far, and blockers or errors you are facing.

The primary issue is that it does not inherently index files or allow sorting based on the "LastModified" metadata. This is problematic for my use case:
I save the timestamp of my last sync. For subsequent operations, I need to identify files that were created or updated after this timestamp. Currently, I must retrieve the metadata for all files and then check each one sequentially using a foreach loop. With millions of files to manage, doing this every 10 seconds is impractical.
Is there a more efficient way to retrieve files based on their metadata without having to pull everything?
